# TeX.SE icon in FontAwesome

Tags: feature-request

The FontAwesome 4.2.0 contains a glyph for [StackExchange icon](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/stack-exchange/).

Is there any possibility to be created an icon for TeX.SE so we could use it with LuaLaTeX?

Comment: What would that look like?

Comment: @Werner, maybe that pretty pair of curly braces (empty of with `\TeX` inside it). The braces has some special colour effect.

Comment: None of the [FontAwesome icons](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/) have shading in it; it's blank-and-white. As such, reproducing the [tex.se] logo would be as simple as `\{\TeX\}` which you can scale to your hearts content using `\resizebox` or `\scalebox` from [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx).

Comment: @Werner, thanks for commenting. But do you know the font used here on TeX.SE to draw that logo? Also, it could be nice to have a negative version of the braces, I mean, a black box with white braces.

Comment: related http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/638/site-design-ideas-updated-with-mockup

Comment: Is this a Meta question?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer It _is_ about the site I think, so it can sit here. It would be, however, fine on the main site as well, probably ;)

Comment: @yo': It's alright, I was unsure.

Comment: I don't think the {feature-request} tag is appropriate here; that tag is meant for feature requests for the site design/functionality. What you're talking about here is a completely separate "product" if you will.

Comment: @PaulGessler, thanks. I asked here because I thought some user could draw the icon and insert it into the font. I don't know if this is possible.

Comment: @Sigur only possible with some local copy of the font. All requests for official inclusion in the font should go through the font creator's [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome); the issue tracker has a ["new icon" label](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/labels/new%20icon) for this purpose.